# Why does the compiler allow references to be used for run-time polymorphism in C++?

Tags: c++11, reference, polymorphism, runtime, virtual

My concern is about run-time polymorphism. I quite understand the notion of using base-class pointers and the "virtual" keyword in order to achieve it. And I do understand why the compiler defers call resolution to run-time. But, I am confused thinking why the compiler would defer it when references are used, instead of pointers. A reference, once assigned, cannot refer to anything else. So, doesn't the compiler already know what object the reference refers to? So, why doesn't it statically resolve function calls when there is a base-class reference, not pointer? **This is different for a pointer because it can point to any object at run-time within the class hierarchy. But the reference is fixed!**

Here is a code snippet:

```
class Base
{
protected:
   int m_value;

public:
   Base(int value)
    : m_value(value)
   {
  }

   virtual const char* getName() const { return "Base"; }
   int getValue() const { return m_value; }
};

class Derived: public Base 
{
public:
   Derived(int value)
       : Base(value)
  {
   }

virtual const char* getName() const { return "Derived"; }
};

int main()
{
   Derived derived(5);
   std::cout << "derived is a " << derived.getName() << " and has value " << 
   derived.getValue() << '\n';

Base &ref = derived;
std::cout << "ref is a " << ref.getName() << " and has value " << ref.getValue() << '\n';

Base *ptr = &derived;
std::cout << "ptr is a " << ptr->getName() << " and has value " << ptr- >getValue() << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The reference is fixed" premise is false. A reference may refer to the base subobject of any object in the hierarchy, just like the pointer can. The compiler cannot tell from the reference what the most-derived object is, no more than it can from the pointer.

Consider:

```
void DoSomething(const Base& b) { std::cout << b.getName(); }

Base base;
DoSomething(base);  // b is bound to Base object. Prints "Base"

Derived derived;
DoSomething(derived);  // b is bound to Base subobject of Derived object.
                       // Prints "Derived"
```

Comment: Oh, yes, passing an object is a scenario I didn't think about. Any sub-object can be passed at run-time as an argument to a method with a base-class reference parameter. That makes sense. But, in the scenario I gave an example of, where the base-class reference is initialized directly with a derived object, isn't the compiler capable of knowing that the reference is referring to a Derived instance?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What difference in the behavior of your example would you expect from a compiler capable of so knowing, compared to a compiler incapable thereof? How do you know the compiler is or isn't doing what you believe it should or should not be doing, whatever that might be?

Comment: I meant to say, what happens here? Base &ref = derived; The compiler in my example surely knows that the object "ref" refers to is an instance of Derived. Therefore, can't the compiler statically determine call resolution for  ref.getName()?

Comment: That is, indeed, [a valid optimization](http://blog.llvm.org/2017/03/devirtualization-in-llvm-and-clang.html). The output of the program would be the same either way, the only way to determine whether that optimization was in fact performed is to examine the generated assembly. The question you ask in your original post is, "why doesn't it statically resolve function calls" - but what evidence do you have that it doesn't do just that?

Comment: Your last comments sum it up all. It has been quite a wonderful discussion, Igor. I can now move on. Here is a green tick mark for you. :-)